# How to calculate page loading time in access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access VBA for web data extraction, currently my code is working fine, but I am facing issue when I disable java script on some pages then pages not loaded properly i.e pages taking too much time in loading, now I want to calculate page loading time in VBA and if page is taking too much time in loading, then I want to move on next page.

My existing code is given below:

```
Ie.navigate url1234
ctime = Now
dtime = (DateDiff("n", ltime, Now))
' MsgBox (dtime)

If dtime > 18000 Then
    MsgBox ("too much time")
End If
```

I am using above code for loading time calculation but code is not working as per my requirement.

Comment: Of course you should place `ctime = Now` before `Ie.navigate`. This gives you the load time (if the granularity of `Now()` is sufficient), but you can't interrupt in this way.

Comment: But during loading how to calculate time after specific interval as when we disable javascript for following page then it take too much time for loading in ie

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07R5HB5C6

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `state` of the IE object in a while loop to determine what you want to do.

As Paul mentionned in the comments, you might want to calculate the time before the `ie.navigate` call.

Hence, you could try something like this :

```
Start = Timer
ie.navigate url1234

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
    ' If its more than 60 seconds...
    If Round(Timer - Start, 2) > 60 Then
        ' Whatever you want to do if it's past 60 seconds...
        MsgBox ("too much time")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop

' Some other code if it's succesful and within the 60 seconds below ..
```

I have also used `timer` instead of `Now()` as I find it much more practical to use than `Now()` when it comes to timing queries and functions.

Cheers!